How to approach minification of HTML literals inside JS bundle
I have a small node app using webpack and babel to render the production JS -- generate an optimised and minified js bundle.
In the source JS, for clarity and easy maintenance, I have HTML literals like this example:
breadcrumbsElement.innerHTML = `
        <ul class="breadcrumb mr-breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a href="/">HostShop</a>
            </li>
            ${breadcrumbLabel ? `
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <span>${breadcrumbLabel}</span>
            </li>` : ''}
        </ul>
    `;

However when I do npm run build the html literals render with whitespaces encoded:
r.innerHTML = `\n\t\t<ul class="breadcrumb mr-breadcrumb">\n\t\t\t<li class="breadcrumb-item">\n\t\t\t\t<a href="/">HostShop</a>\n\t\t\t</li>\n\t\t\t${t ? `\n\t\t\t<li class="breadcrumb-item">\n\t\t\t\t<span>${t}</span>\n\t\t\t</li>` : ""}\n\t\t</ul>\n\t`;

The unnecessary whitespaces between HTML tags (which don’t have anything to do with functionality just presentation) are encoded and preserved, which I believe is the minification/bundler issue.
I tried few popular tools such as terser, but without luck.
What’s the best approach to minify this?

What is the problem you encounter with white space? Removing them while you have classnames that take up more space than those tabs seems an insignificant "optimisation".

Those are unnecessary: \n\t\t\t it like minifier gives me 2 characters for each single white space isn’t it, but good catch about CSS class names!

What's your metric for "best"? How can compare two approaches and measure which one is better?

not changing the source code readability significantly would be the metric for ‘best'

I see a library or two when I search “minify html in template literals”.

Chances are you are using innerText instead of textContent somewhere in your code.

The whitespaces are preserved for a very good reason, ruining strings would be bad for any minifier. There's no common tool that does this, this would custom babel plugin or something similar. And this would require to additionally mark the strings that need to be transformed somehow, so other strings won't be affected. And when whitespaces that are supposed to be there will be deleted, this will cause issues. The question is too unspecific for SO ("best" is an indicator).

IMO there's no "best" here because this looks like busywork with no real profit. Whitespace is gzipped well. And any solution that tries to solve this with syntax instead of code-breaking minifiers will take more chars in source code than that, including JSX. E.g. the simplest thing to do which is actually useful for multilines, innerHTML = [   \`,       ``, ...].join('')or just`...` + `...`` , it still uses 3+ extra chars per line

I’m guessing that bundler (webpack in this case) just cannot currently detect whether we need those white-spaces or not; thinking HTML inside  or  tags vs just regular HTML that doesn’t require white-spaces in-between tags.

The tools you are mentionning are there to minify javascript code, not your data. They won't interpret your literals and decide for you what is relevant or not.
If you don't want these spaces, do not add them in the first place.
/**
 * Create an HTML element
 * @param {string} tagName - The tag name of the element
 * @param {Record<string, string>} attributes - The attributes of the element
 * @param {string} children - The children of the element
 * @returns {string} The HTML string of the element
 */
const createElement = (tagName, attributes, children) =>
    `<${tagName}${
        attributes != null
            ? Object.entries(attributes)
                  .map(([key, value]) => ` ${key === 'className' ? 'class' : key}="${value}"`)
                  .join('')
            : ''
    }${children != null && children.length > 0 ? `>${children.filter(Boolean).join('')}</${tagName}>` : ''}`;

breadcrumElement.innerHTML = createElement('ul', { className: 'breadcrumb mr-breadcrumb' }, [
    createElement('li', { className: 'breadcrumb-item' }, [
        createElement('a', { href: '/' }, ['HostShop']),
        breadcrumbLabel ? createElement('span', { className: 'breadcrumb-item' }, [breadcrumbLabel]) : null,
    ]),
]);

You will have one more function in your code but your minified code will be smaller.
You also will have to rewrite you literals but your code will be easier to manage.
Some tools could help for that.
But at this point why not just use React/jsx?

Note that it's what React uses: for example, the code compiles to React.createElement("ul", {class: "breadcrumb mr-breadcrumb"}, React.createElement("li", {class: "breadcrumb-item"}, React.createElement("a", {href: "/"}, "HostShop")), breadcrumbLabel ? React.createElement("li", {class: "breadcrumb-item"}, React.createElement("span", null, breadcrumbLabel)) : null) in React.

the react look-alike implemetation was intentional :)

This solution actually enlarged the minified code by a kilobyte or two in my small bundle, haven’t tested on a larger codbase tho. Seems harder on CPU also.

Weird as the minified createElement calls should be like 40% smaller than your initial literal (the example given). You have to find a way to define the function only once though. As for the CPU usage of course it's more intensive, but compression comes at a cost.

It is better to avoid nesting the literals, chaining is better and way more easier to read.
There is chances that it is also faster to parse.
In this case the ternary is wrapped into parenthesis, so the chaining is not broken.


breadcrumbLabel = `I 
Am<br>
Multiline :)
`

breadcrumbsElement.innerHTML = `
        <ul class="breadcrumb mr-breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a href="/">HostShop</a>
            </li>` +
            (breadcrumbLabel ? `
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <span>${breadcrumbLabel}</span>
            </li>` : '') + '</ul>';
<div id=breadcrumbsElement>




With this approach (using webpack minifier) I’m not getting the tabs encoded to ‘\t’ but left as they were which some mentioned is handled by gzip anyway so I guess it is a win: t.innerHTML='\n        <ul class="breadcrumb mr-breadcrumb">\n            <li class="breadcrumb-item">\n                <a href="/">HostShop</a>\n            </li>'+(r?'\n            <li class="breadcrumb-item">\n                <span>'.concat(r,"</span>\n            </li>"):"")+"</ul>"

Why not just remove them yourself?
breadcrumbsElement.innerHTML = `
        <ul class="breadcrumb mr-breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <a href="/">HostShop</a>
            </li>
            ${breadcrumbLabel ? `
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                <span>${breadcrumbLabel}</span>
            </li>` : ''}
        </ul>
    `.replace(/[\n\t]/g, "");

I have used this approach in production to emulate JSX-style code in an environment where I had to use vanilla JS.
/[\n\t]/g is a regular expression that matches every newline and tab character in the string. If you don't want a particular newline or tab character to be removed, you can use the HTML entities &#10; (newline) and &#9; (tab).

I realized that the question was asking for the characters to be removed in the bundled JS rather than the HTML so probably ignore this unless your bundler is smart enough to call the replace() method at compile-time...

Correct, this ‘hack' was mentioned earlier (deleted by author) actually works with webpack/babel-based bundler and produces a optimised, minified code. I don’t like it tho because it kinda contaminates the source code with something totally unrelated to functionality.
